# Quickly find first/last row in table

Tags: mysql

Finding the first row of a table with an alpha date/time (eg. "20200515.152300") of a particular table is taking a long time.  I am using this query:

```
SELECT path FROM tsFileListTbl WHERE `tsNum` = 18 AND path LIKE "/mnt/das.h%" ORDER BY `dateTime` ASC LIMIT 1;
+----------------------------------+
| path                             |
+----------------------------------+
| /mnt/das.h/18/20200207.204900.ts |
+----------------------------------+
1 row in set (14.32 sec)
```

Where:

```
DESCRIBE tsFileListTbl;
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| tsNum       | int(11)             | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| path        | varchar(128)        | NO   | UNI |         |                |
| dateTime    | char(15)            | YES  | MUL |         |                |
| endDateTime | char(15)            | YES  |     |         |                |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.60 sec)
```

And...

```
SHOW INDEXES ON tsFileListTbl;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON tsFileListTbl' at line 1
mysql> SHOW INDEX FROM tsFileListTbl;
+---------------+------------+------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table         | Non_unique | Key_name         | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+---------------+------------+------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| tsFileListTbl |          0 | PRIMARY          |            1 | id          | A         |     3159454 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tsFileListTbl |          0 | path             |            1 | path        | A         |     3159454 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tsFileListTbl |          1 | dateTimeIdx      |            1 | dateTime    | A         |     1579727 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| tsFileListTbl |          1 | tsNumDateIdx     |            1 | tsNum       | A         |          36 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tsFileListTbl |          1 | tsNumDateIdx     |            2 | dateTime    | A         |     3159454 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| tsFileListTbl |          1 | tsNumPathDateIdx |            1 | tsNum       | A         |          36 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tsFileListTbl |          1 | tsNumPathDateIdx |            2 | path        | A         |     3159454 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tsFileListTbl |          1 | tsNumPathDateIdx |            3 | dateTime    | A         |     3159454 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
+---------------+------------+------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
8 rows in set (1.41 sec)
```

Is there anything I could do, without changing the table field definitions, to improve the query time?

Linux / Centos 6 / 32-bit

`mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.73, for redhat-linux-gnu (i386) using readline 5.1`

**EDIT I**

I ran the query directly from mysql to look at different measurements.

```
show processlist
Query   |  188 | Sending data | SELECT path FROM tsFileListTbl WHERE `tsNum` = 18 AND path LIKE "/mnt/das.h%" ...
```

In all the query took **4 minutes 20 seconds** to complete.

```
mysql> explain SELECT path FROM tsFileListTbl WHERE `tsNum` = 18 AND path LIKE "/mnt/das.h%" ORDER BY `dateTime` ASC LIMIT 1;
+----+-------------+---------------+-------+------------------------------------+-------------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table         | type  | possible_keys                      | key         | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------------+-------+------------------------------------+-------------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tsFileListTbl | index | path,tsNumDateIdx,tsNumPathDateIdx | dateTimeIdx | 46      | NULL | 15931 | Using where |
+----+-------------+---------------+-------+------------------------------------+-------------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
```

`EXPLAIN` is new to me.  Does the output above mean that the `dateTimeIdx` was used for the query?  If so, that would be the correct index, right?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tsFileListTbl;
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|  2913301 |
+----------+
1 row in set (34.77 sec)
```

**EDIT II**

As requested, here is the output from `SHOW CREATE TABLE tsFileListTbl`:

```
CREATE TABLE `tsFileListTbl` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tsNum` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `path` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `dateTime` char(15) DEFAULT '',
  `endDateTime` char(15) DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `path` (`path`),
  KEY `dateTimeIdx` (`dateTime`),
  KEY `tsNumDateIdx` (`tsNum`,`dateTime`),
  KEY `tsNumPathDateIdx` (`tsNum`,`path`,`dateTime`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3015594 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**EDIT III**

One of the indices suggested by Rick James was already there. After adding the other one, the query ran faster, not not that much faster:

```
mysql> SELECT path FROM tsFileListTbl WHERE `tsNum` = 18 AND path LIKE "/mnt/das.h%" ORDER BY `dateTime` ASC LIMIT 1;
+----------------------------------+
| path                             |
+----------------------------------+
| /mnt/das.h/18/20200208.035900.ts |
+----------------------------------+
1 row in set (2 min 5.44 sec)

mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT path FROM tsFileListTbl WHERE `tsNum` = 18 AND path LIKE "/mnt/das.h%" ORDER BY `dateTime` ASC LIMIT 1;
+----+-------------+---------------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------+-------------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table         | type  | possible_keys                                       | key         | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------+-------------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tsFileListTbl | index | path,tsNumDateIdx,tsNumPathDateIdx,tsNumDatePathIdx | dateTimeIdx | 46      | NULL | 2912893 | Using where |
+----+-------------+---------------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------+-------------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)

CREATE TABLE `tsFileListTbl` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tsNum` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `path` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `dateTime` char(15) DEFAULT '',
  `endDateTime` char(15) DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `path` (`path`),
  KEY `dateTimeIdx` (`dateTime`),
  KEY `tsNumDateIdx` (`tsNum`,`dateTime`),
  KEY `tsNumPathDateIdx` (`tsNum`,`path`,`dateTime`),
  KEY `tsNumDatePathIdx` (`tsNum`,`dateTime`,`path`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3015730 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**EDIT IV**

I tried the "IGNORE INDEX" as suggested by Rick James.  It takes half the time as the previous time but still about 1 minute to find the first row.  Is that the best I can expect?  I was hoping to find first/last row in the order of *milliseconds* not seconds...

```
SELECT path FROM tsFileListTbl IGNORE INDEX(dateTimeIdx) WHERE `tsNum` = 18 AND path LIKE "/mnt/das.h%" ORDER BY `dateTime` ASC LIMIT 1;

+----------------------------------+
| path                             |
+----------------------------------+
| /mnt/das.h/18/20200208.055500.ts |
+----------------------------------+
1 row in set (57.17 sec)

mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT path FROM tsFileListTbl IGNORE INDEX(dateTimeIdx) WHERE `tsNum` = 18 AND path LIKE "/mnt/das.h%" ORDER BY `dateTime` ASC LIMIT 1;
+----+-------------+---------------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------+--------------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table         | type  | possible_keys                                       | key          | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------+--------------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tsFileListTbl | range | path,tsNumDateIdx,tsNumPathDateIdx,tsNumDatePathIdx | tsNumDateIdx | 4       | NULL | 125828 | Using where |
+----+-------------+---------------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------+--------------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.16 sec)
```

**EDIT V**

```
FLUSH STATUS;
SELECT path FROM tsFileListTbl WHERE `tsNum` = 18 AND path LIKE "/mnt/das.h%" ORDER BY `dateTime` ASC LIMIT 1;
+----------------------------------+
| path                             |
+----------------------------------+
| /mnt/das.h/18/20200208.083300.ts |
+----------------------------------+
1 row in set (10.51 sec)

mysql> SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';
+----------------------------+---------+
| Variable_name              | Value   |
+----------------------------+---------+
| Handler_commit             | 1       |
| Handler_delete             | 0       |
| Handler_discover           | 0       |
| Handler_prepare            | 0       |
| Handler_read_first         | 1       |
| Handler_read_key           | 1       |
| Handler_read_next          | 1498109 |
| Handler_read_prev          | 0       |
| Handler_read_rnd           | 0       |
| Handler_read_rnd_next      | 0       |
| Handler_rollback           | 0       |
| Handler_savepoint          | 0       |
| Handler_savepoint_rollback | 0       |
| Handler_update             | 0       |
| Handler_write              | 0       |
+----------------------------+---------+
15 rows in set (0.46 sec)
```

**EDIT VI**

Ignoring all indices except for one improves the performance a lot on the test system.  Will try on the production machine.

```
SELECT path FROM tsFileListTbl IGNORE INDEX(dateTimeIdx, tsNumDateIdx,tsNumPathDateIdx) WHERE `tsNum` = 18 AND path LIKE "/mnt/das.h%" ORDER BY `dateTime` ASC LIMIT 1;
+----------------------------------+
| path                             |
+----------------------------------+
| /mnt/das.h/18/20200209.092000.ts |
+----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.71 sec)

EXPLAIN  SELECT path FROM tsFileListTbl IGNORE INDEX(dateTimeIdx, tsNumDateIdx,tsNumPathDateIdx) WHERE `tsNum` = 18 AND path LIKE "/mnt/das.h%" ORDER BY `dateTime` ASC LIMIT 1;
+----+-------------+---------------+------+-----------------------+------------------+---------+-------+--------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table         | type | possible_keys         | key              | key_len | ref   | rows   | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+---------------+------+-----------------------+------------------+---------+-------+--------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tsFileListTbl | ref  | path,tsNumDatePathIdx | tsNumDatePathIdx | 4       | const | 298080 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+---------------+------+-----------------------+------------------+---------+-------+--------+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**EDIT VII**

Taking Rick James' suggestion, to avoid the wildcard search, we added a column `partPath` and changed app to support to support it.

```
CREATE TABLE `tsFileListTbl` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tsNum` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `partPath` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `path` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `dateTime` char(15) DEFAULT '',
  `endDateTime` char(15) DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `path` (`path`),
  KEY `dateTimeIdx` (`dateTime`),
  KEY `tsNumDateIdx` (`tsNum`,`dateTime`),
  KEY `tsNumPathDateIdx` (`tsNum`,`path`,`dateTime`),
  KEY `partPathDateIdx` (`partPath`,`dateTime`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2906868 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Good news: search time is very very much faster.

```
SELECT path FROM tsFileListTbl IGNORE INDEX(dateTimeIdx, tsNumDateIdx, tsNumPathDateIdx) WHERE `tsNum` = 12 AND   `partPath` = "/mnt/das.b" ORDER BY `dateTime` ASC LIMIT 1;
+----------------------------------+
| path                             |
+----------------------------------+
| /mnt/das.b/12/20191013.061400.ts |
+----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

explain SELECT path FROM tsFileListTbl IGNORE INDEX(dateTimeIdx, tsNumDateIdx, tsNumPathDateIdx) WHERE `tsNum` = 23 AND   `partPath` = "/mnt/das.b" ORDER BY `dateTime` ASC LIMIT 1;
+----+-------------+---------------+------+-----------------+-----------------+---------+-------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table         | type | possible_keys   | key             | key_len | ref   | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------------+------+-----------------+-----------------+---------+-------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tsFileListTbl | ref  | partPathDateIdx | partPathDateIdx | 63      | const | 991200 | Using where |
+----+-------------+---------------+------+-----------------+-----------------+---------+-------+--------+-------------+
```

**However** the query still takes 2-3 seconds *if there is no data*.  ie, no rows match the query.  Why would that be?  How can I get the same (fast) response regardless of whether there is data or not?

Comment: using `EXPLAIN` on your query will provide a lot of info as to why it is so slow, but I'm guess the main issue would be the full text search on `path`. Sorting for time using a char column doesn't help either - you should have used a `DATETIME` column.

Comment: Your dateTime wouldn't perchance correspond to the name of the file?

Comment: Constraints in the application made it difficult to use a `DATETIME` rather than textual date/time.  Yes, the dateTime is the root of the filename but there are various extensions, so like "20200515.231200.ts", ".xx", ".yy", ".zz" etc

Comment: 1.5M -- That's half the table?!  I added a bunch to my Answer.  If `ORDER BY path` is as good as `ORDER BY dateTime`, then you have another solution.

Comment: @Danny - as I've discussed in my answer and comments, it looks like the best index would be `tsNumDatePathIdx` and as long as you can't get the optimizer to use it, you will get bad results. I have not seen it being used in any of your examples. Please note that `IGNORE INDEX` can accept **multiple** indexes to ignore! That being said, you should try just forcing one of the indexes using `FORCE INDEX (index_name)` and try out all of your indexes until you find the one that works best. Also, it could be that your database server has other performance issues, such as insufficient hardware...

Answer (score 1):

Add these two indexes:

```
INDEX(tsNum, path, datetime)
INDEX(tsNum, datetime, path)
```

If you want *both* the first and last, then use `UNION ALL`.

When showing a schema, please use `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; it is more descriptive than `DESCRIBE`.

**Discussion**

For

```
SELECT path FROM tsFileListTbl
    WHERE `tsNum` = 18 AND path LIKE "/mnt/das.h%"
    ORDER BY `dateTime` ASC LIMIT 1;

INDEX(tsNum, path, datetime)
```

Here is what is being done:

- Since the index is "covering", all the work will be done in the index's BTree; no need to look in the data's BTree.  `EXPLAIN` says `Using index` to indicate "covering".
- It will drill down the BTree to find the first row with `tsNum = 18 AND path LIKE "/mnt/das.h%"`.  This is very fast.
- Then it will scan forward in the BTree to collect all the rows matching that.  In one of your tests, it seems there were 1.5M such rows.  Of course, changing the `18` or the `LIKE` string will change this count, *possibly a lot*.  This probably takes half the time of the query.
- After that, sort on `dateTime` -- another half of the time
- Finally, deliver the first row.  Changing the value in the `LIMIT` won't change the timing much.

The cause of a performance problem can be characterized as "having a 'range' (LIKE '...%') *and* an unrelated `ORDER BY`"

**Split the path**

If `path` were split into `base` and `rest` such that the query were

```
SELECT base, rest FROM tsFileListTbl
    WHERE `tsNum` = 18
      AND base = "/mnt/das.h"   -- no range
    ORDER BY `dateTime` ASC LIMIT 1;
```

Then this can handle the entire query extremely fast, regardless of the number of rows with [18,"/mnt/das.h"].  It would need

```
INDEX(tsNum, base,  -- either order is OK
      datetime,     -- for the order by
      rest)         -- for covering (last)
```

The query would function thus:

- Reach into the index BTree for the *last* row matching tsNum and base, where "last" is given by dateTime.  The Handler numbers will be essentially "1".

Comment: The first index was already there. I added the second.  See above for the results.

Comment: @Danny - Try this:  `SELECT path FROM tsFileListTbl IGNORE INDEX(dateTimeIdx) WHERE ...`  I'm thinking that the Optimizer is using that index when it should not.

Comment: Hi Rick, results are above.  It take half the time, but still 1 minute.

Comment: @Danny - If you want to discuss this further, please get the [Handler counts](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#handler_counts) .  (That won't lead to a solution, just an understanding -- maybe.)

Comment: Hi Rick, you've been very helpful. Thanks.  I've added the Handler Counts above.  Perhaps there is a way to change the schema to improve speed?  (of course the application would need to change too).  What about splitting the `path` into two pieces, the `/mnt/das.h` prefix part and the rest of the path?

Comment: Hi Rick, splitting the path is the right solution in the long term but that would need a lot of application redesign. Ignoring the other indices dramatically improved the performance so we'll try that on a production machine first.

Comment: Adding a new column to the table dramatically improved performance. But its still slow if there are now rows.  I've appended that information to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I ran some tests, and on my setup - which is different, using MariaDB 10, Docker, 64-bit, but should still map well to the same constraints - the problem seems to be that the database prefers to use the `tsNumDateIdx` even though it is less effective. After dropping it, the database resorts to `tsNumPathDateIdx` which speeds up my queries by about 20 times.

I can't explain why the database chooses a slower index - using `tsNumDateIdx` means you get fast filter only on the `tsNum` lookup and then the database has to be "`Using where`" for the path filter which is very slow.

AS mentioned in the comments, in these kinds of situations - `EXPLAIN` is your friend - if the results look weird, like in my case (see below), then fiddle with your indexes.

- My tests:

```
MariaDB [test]> explain select path FROM filelist WHERE `tsNum` = 18 AND path LIKE "/home/odeda/%" ORDER BY `dateTime` ASC LIMIT 1;
+------+-------------+----------+-------+------------------------------------+--------------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table    | type  | possible_keys                      | key          | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra       |
+------+-------------+----------+-------+------------------------------------+--------------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | filelist | range | path,tsNumDateIdx,tsNumPathDateIdx | tsNumDateIdx | 4       | NULL | 19534 | Using where |
+------+-------------+----------+-------+------------------------------------+--------------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [test]> select count(path) FROM filelist WHERE `tsNum` = 18 AND path LIKE "/home/odeda/%" ORDER BY `dateTime` ASC LIMIT 1;
+-------------+
| count(path) |
+-------------+
|        2607 |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.165 sec)
```

```
MariaDB [test]> alter table filelist drop index tsNumDateIdx;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.046 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

```
MariaDB [test]> explain select path FROM filelist WHERE `tsNum` = 18 AND path LIKE "/home/odeda/Documents%" ORDER BY `dateTime` ASC LIMIT 1;
+------+-------------+----------+-------+-----------------------+------------------+---------+------+-------+------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table    | type  | possible_keys         | key              | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra                                    |
+------+-------------+----------+-------+-----------------------+------------------+---------+------+-------+------------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | filelist | range | path,tsNumPathDateIdx | tsNumPathDateIdx | 134     | NULL | 27361 | Using where; Using index; Using filesort |
+------+-------------+----------+-------+-----------------------+------------------+---------+------+-------+------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [test]> select count(path) FROM filelist WHERE `tsNum` = 18 AND path LIKE "/home/odeda/Documents%" ORDER BY `dateTime` ASC LIMIT 1;
+-------------+
| count(path) |
+-------------+
|        2913 |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.008 sec)
```

Comment: Thank you.  I'll investigate using `EXPLAIN` and see which indices are used in what order.

Comment: Be aware:  The distribution of the data values can have a big effect on the speed of the queries and whether the Optimizer picks the "right" index.  (This is because of two ranges involved (LIKE and ORDER BY).

Comment: In your edits I can see in the explain that the database used the index on the date field. This is useless as you aren't even filtering on that. Use the `IGNORE` syntax Rick suggested to blacklist indexes until you get good behaviour (then consider removing useless indexes from the table - any index that doesn't speedup queries has negative impact as indexes slow updates)

Comment: @Guss - In some situations, the Optimizer will decide to use an `INDEX` to handle the `ORDER BY` even when it can't handle the `WHERE`.  This can, however, backfire -- it may have to scan the entire table before it finds any [tsNum,path] pair that matches the `WHERE`.

Comment: @RickJames Yea, this looks like the case - but unless the where clause will cause a significant portion of the table to be retrieved - making a full table scan needed just for the data retrieval, and I don't think that is the case, there is no reason to do that, and it looks like the optimizer is just wrong. I wonder what edge case is needed to trigger this broken behavior.

Comment: "I was hoping to find first/last row in the order of milliseconds not seconds."  Then you really need to split the path so that it can be `WHERE foo = '/mnt/das.h' ORDER BY datetime LIMIT 1` -- That will give a Handler_read count of only "1" and run in only millisecond(s).

Comment: Think of it this way...  Imagine a list of a million people names and birthdates.  And you wanted the youngest person who's name started with "D".  But how would you arrange a list to make it fast to discover such?  You can focus on either the name or the date, but not both simultaneously.  INDEXes are inherently 1-dimensional; you need a 2D index.